# C# Mailkit/Mimekit SSL cipher issue, unable to send/recv emails

Tags: c#, email, ssl, wireshark, mailkit

I am writing a C# email app (an email client). However, an error comes up every time I try to start a TLS session with my server, and debugging via Wireshark shows that there is some kind of TLS/SSL issue causing the connection to be reset

Client ---> C# application using MAILKIT/MIMEKIT (MS VS 2015)

Server ---> Email server Linux based, Self signed certificate assigned.

Now, when I use Thunderbird to connect (send/recv emails) to my mail server everything goes fine, but if I use my app shows an error.

1. Mailkit/Mimekit Wireshark TLS capture [image: 01]
2. Cipher suites sent by the Mailkit/Mimekit to my the server
   [image: 02]
3. Cipher accepted by the server [image: 03]
4. Thunderbird Wireshark TLS capture [image: 04]
5. Ciphersuites sent by the Thunderbird to my server [image: 05]
6. Cipher accepted by the server [image: 06]
7. Error shown by the my C# APP [image: 07]

Error shown in Mail server Logs:

> SSL_accept error from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: Connection reset by
>   peer

Can anyone guide me what to do ? I cant change/update the CIPHERSUITE at my server side. Also, in my code I have ignored the UNTRUSTED CERTIFICATE check so error is not coming because of the self signed certificate.

Comment: This does not really look like a problem with ciphers. The client closes the connection after it received the servers successful response - which means that the server successfully selected a cipher from the ones offered by the client. It is more likely that the client closed because it did not like the servers certificate. But there are not enough information in your question to further track down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by adding the following line before CONNECT command inside my C# code. Code added:

```
client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11;
```

However, still the SAME cipher (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA) is sent by the CLIENT and ACCEPTED by the server. This is TLS 1.1 running, while thunderbird uses TLS1.2 and it works flawlessly.

Although this is actually resolved the issue, but I still its not TLS1.2.

`client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;` 
brings back the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Tls11 and Tls12:

```
client.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

Comment: but the mailkit/mimekit doesnt connects with the server with TLS1.2, only uses TLS1.1.

Comment: That's an issue with SslStream

Comment: iam also thinking same.